# I have a problem with HBAR on my Ledger regarding block verification after sending from Hashpack

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I sent some HBAR from my Hashpack to a Ledger Nano device. On the Ledger, they are displayed correctly and the balance is updated, but when checking with Hashscan, it shows an error and the block is not valid. Can someone help me? I sent these HBAR 2 years ago.
Thanks

The HBAR were sent to the Ledger from the Hashpack, indeed the balance on the Ledger is correct, but when checking the block through Hashscan, it shows an error and therefore they do not appear. Could it be that the Ledger at the time did not integrate HBAR correctly?